# Iron session is not updating req.session object

Tags: session, next.js

I have a page where users can give themselves a "role" like member or admin. They can go to another route to create messages. I am trying to update user's role from "user" to "admin". It updates `req.session` to admin role in the `admin.js` file, but when I go to messages/create.js and try to log `req.session`, it shows that user still has the "user" role. I am saving the changes I make by calling `req.session.save()`, but it is not working.

admin.js

```
import { withIronSessionApiRoute } from "iron-session/next";
import nc from "next-connect";
import { session_config } from "../../lib/config";
import Users from "../../models/user";
import { connectToDatabase } from "../../util/mongodb";

const handler = nc()

handler.post(async (req) => {
    if (req.body.password === process.env.ADMIN_PASSWORD) {
        await connectToDatabase()
        await Users.findOneAndUpdate({ name: req.session.user.name }, { role: "admin" })
        const updated_user = { name: req.session.user.name, role: "admin" }

        req.session.user = updated_user
        await req.session.save()

    }

})

export default withIronSessionApiRoute(handler, session_config);
```

messages/create.js

```
import { withIronSessionApiRoute } from "iron-session/next";
import nc from "next-connect";
import { session_config } from "../../../lib/config";

const handler = nc()
handler.post(async (req) => {
    console.log(req.session.user)
    console.log(req.body)
})

export default withIronSessionApiRoute(handler, session_config)
```

Please let me know what the issue is and how I can fix it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I noticed from looking at the code is that you're not sending a response back to the client. Iron session uses cookies to manage stateless authentication and the way it manages is by setting the `response header`. Because you're not sending a response, it can't update the session.

Looking further into the [API documentation](https://github.com/vvo/iron-session#sessionsave), `session.save()` - "*Saves the session and sets the cookie header to be sent* **once the response is sent**."

Not knowing your full implementation or having a working code example from something like [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io), I suggest the following code to see if this solves your problem.

```js
// please make sure that `res` is a parameter on the `.post()` function 
// on your original code. I've already set it as shown below.

handler.post(async (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.password === process.env.ADMIN_PASSWORD) {
        await connectToDatabase()
        await Users.findOneAndUpdate({ name: req.session.user.name }, { role: "admin" })
        const updated_user = { name: req.session.user.name, role: "admin" }

        req.session.user = updated_user
        await req.session.save()
        // response below
        res.send({ ok: true })
        // or if you don't want to send custom data back, comment the line above,
        // and then uncomment the line below
        // res.status(200).end()
    }
})
```

---

### Attempt 2

I made an [iron session demo on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/iron-session-example-t7ou6e) using some of the demo code from the [iron session repo NextJs example](https://github.com/vvo/iron-session/tree/main/examples/next.js).

The code example shows:

- login
- log out
- setting a user as an admin
- fetching user data from server-side
- fetching user data from client-side
- fetching using [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/)

Some side notes to be aware of: if you are doing something like
`const sessionData = req.session.user`, then trying to mutate the req.session.user, and then sending the data back, it won't work *because the session object will be recreated per request and node cannot store `req.session` as a reference*.

If my demo doesn't help you, then you're going to have to share more info and code, and maybe create a Codesandbox to **reproduce what is happening to you**.

Comment: I copy pasted your code and it didn't work. When I am on admin route, it changes the user object in req.session to admin, but when I am on `/messages/create` route, and console log req.session, it shows that the user's role has not changed.

Comment: I couldn't ask via a comment on your question because my "privileges" level is too low... Anyways, are you calling `admin.js` from a directory like `pages/admin.js` or from the `api` folder (`pages/api/admin.js`)?

Comment: I have a file called admin in pages folder and another admin.js file in pages/api. I am calling the one in pages/api.

Comment: Please see my attempt #2.

Comment: I truly appreciate your effort in helping me, but I am not using server side props. So, your code doesn't really match with mine. I am actually using axios to call my backend, and use SWR to get user info for getting user info on frontend. So, can you please try to create it with that? I am having trouble creating next app on codesandbox, because they are too many dependencies and it's complicated. I would have sent you my repo, but I am using mongo db, and you will need the db password to make it work.

Comment: Server side props was just one example. The `fetch` functions work just like axios and is similar to SWR. I've update the codesandbox to show SWR function. If you're using axios, `fetch` has been around for a good while now and there is no need to use 3rd party fetchers. For axios on node, fetch is coming to node as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248923/discussion-between-l1qu1d-and-aryan-arora).